# Space and time complexity

Tags: sorting, time, compare, complexity-theory, space

```
function compareStringLengths ( a, b )
{
  if ( a.length < b.length )
    return -1;
  if ( a.length > b.length )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var fruits = [ "apple", "pear", "orange", "banana" ];
fruits.sort ( compareStringLengths );
```

Can someone please tell me the time and space complexity of this code? I'm guessing the time complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: What language is it?

Answer (score 0):

Space complexity: linear, i.e. O(n) (because all your data is in an array)
Time complexity: O(n log(n)) (because of sorting)